# Structural find and replace IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I need to search for occurrences of a method, change the name, preserve the method body, add an annotation to the method, and ensure that the annotation is imported.  I need to do this in multiple classes project wide.

The docs just are not making sense to me, can anyone please shed light on this feature and how I might accomplish the following using IntelliJ's Structural Find and Replace feature?

```
import a;
import b;
import c;

public class SomeClass extends SomeAbstractClass implements SomeInterface {

    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
        methodbody.getMoreBody();
    }
}
```

convert to

```
import a;
import b;
import c;
import some.package.with.annotation;

public class SomeClass extends SomeAbstractClass implements SomeInterface {

    @Override
    @annotation
    public void newMethodName() {
        methodbody.getMoreBody();
    }
}
```

Comment: To change the name everywhere, right-click on the method name, select `Refactor -> Rename... -> Rename base method`.

Comment: Yes, but I need to add the annotation and it's import also

Comment: Does the overridden method *always* need the annotation? If you have control over how the annotation is used, would it make sense to annotate the method in the interface/abstract class and look for the annotation on superclass methods using something like Spring's [AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html#findAnnotation-java.lang.reflect.Method-java.lang.Class-)?

Comment: That isn't possible in the usual way for a simple reason: the annotation doesn't "belong" to the method. It's additional info on parts of/the entire class. The case where this specific annotation needs to be part of any declaration of an overriding method simply isn't supported since it contradicts the logic of annotations. If you need the annotation **everywhere** what's the use of the annotation in the first place?

Comment: Good point.  My solution was to use a point cut.  This allowed me to throw out the annotation, making it a simple string replace operation to rename the method as desired.  The pointcut now does the exact same thing as the annotation did, but now all methods of a subclass of my desired method signature will me affected.  Thanks for discussing this and bringing me to the proper conclusion.  I had to stop and ask myself, why do I want to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just simple need one to one replace (no need to search patterns), you don't need structural search.

You can do as follows.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (or **Edit -> Find -> Replace in path**).
- Add following texts to relevant positions

Text to Find: `@Override[\S\s]*public void someMethod`

Replace with: `@Override\n    @annotation\n    public void someMethod`

Click Find & then Apply to all the occurrences.

[image]

- This will do the find & replace part for you.
- Still, this will not import the annotation for you into the .java file. If your import is an unambiguous import, you can import it on a fly by  **Settings** **->** **Type** `auto import` **-> Java -> put tick to** `add unambiguous imports on fly.` Otherwise you have to import them manually for each file. Hope this helps :))

[image]

Comment: I took another route entirely by implementing an Aspect that will do what the annotation does.  But this is the answer I was looking for if I went down the original path.  Thanks!

Comment: @ferahgo nice to see .. :))

Answer (score 0):

The problem at hand is that we want to apply behavior to all methods with a certain name, that exist in a certain class.  The string replace operation to rename the method is simple.   Using intelliJ to do a structural replace may be possible (I really do not know), but can be avoided entirely using a pointcut.

```
@Pointcut(
  "execution(public * someMethod(..))")
private void someMethod() {}

@Pointcut("target(com.company.SomeAbstractClass+)")
private void someAbstractClass() {}

@Before("someMethod && someAbstractClass()")
public void somePointCutAction(Pointcut pointcut) {
  // Some logic to execute before the method that is a
  // child of SomeAbstractClass and has a method name someMethod
}
```